# Unable to install pandas in python 3.5.1 in command prompt

Tags: python, pandas

I tried installing pandas using:

```
pip install pandas
```

and also:

```
C:\Python35\Scripts\pip install pandas
```

but this gave me the following error:

> The system cannot find the path specified.

Does anyone know why?
I have already downloaded and installed python 3.5.1.

Comment: Try installing from binary: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pandas

Comment: You should try to install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), it is easy to deploy and pandas is included.